# Converting Terms to Atoms preserving variable names in YAP prolog

Tags: prolog

Is there a way to configure YAP (and/or SWI prolog) so they will preserve variable names in any call to `term_to_atom/2` ?.

For example, when I execute this:

```
term_to_atom(member(X, [1,2]), A).
```

I obtain this answer:

```
A = 'member(_131405,[1,2])'
```

Where `X` has been replaced by its internal representation.

However, I would like to get this answer instead:

```
A = 'member(X,[1,2])'
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two issues involved.  How to get the variable name `X` into the system, and how to get a term with such a variable into the atom.

The `X` you type in is read by the top level which converts it to a regular variable which does not have a name associated. Let's see that in YAP:

```
   ?- read(Term).
   |: X+3*Y+X.
Term = _A+3*_B+_A
```

The **`|:`** is YAP's prompt for input. And we have entered **`X+3*Y+X.`**  However, the variable `Term` contains `_A` and `_B` (names chosen by the top level) in place of `X` and `Y`. So the information is lost and cannot be restored once it is read by read/1.

You have to access that information differently with the more general built-in for reading `read_term/2,3` and the option `variable_names/1`.

```
   ?- read_term(T,[variable_names(Eqs)]).
   |: X+3*Y+X.
Eqs = ['X'=_A,'Y'=_B],
T = _A+3*_B+_A
```

So the read option `variable_names/1` gives you the information to restore the variable names. For each named variable read by `read_term/2` there is a structure `Name = Variable` where Name is an atom representing the variable name. Above, `'X'` is the name capital X.

Anonymous variables, that is variables whose name is `_`, do not occur in the list of variable names. They can be rapidly extracted like so:

```
 ?- read_term(T,[variable_names(Eqs)]),
    term_variables(Eqs, Named),
    term_variables(Named+T, Vars),
    append(Named, Anons, Vars).
```

So much for the reading.

Now for the writing. We cannot write the term directly but have to accompany it with the list `Eqs`. Let's call the new predicate `term_to_atom(Term, Eqs, Atom)`. In both YAP and SWI there is [`with_output_to(Output, Goal)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=with_output_to/2) which writes the output of `Goal` to different destinations like `atom(A)`. So you can now use write_term/2 to write the term as you please. An example:

```
?- with_output_to(atom(A),write_term('a b'+X,[quoted(true)])).
A = '\'a b\'+_131284'.
```

The variable _131284 looks very ugly. To get variables associated with their names for printing we can implement `term_to_atom/3` as follows:

```
term_to_atom(T, Eqs, A) :-
   with_output_to(atom(A), write_term(T,[variable_names(Eqs),quoted(true)]) ).
```

And use it like so:

```
   ?- read_term(T,[variable_names(Eqs)]), term_to_atom(T, Eqs, Atom).
   |: X+3*Y+X.
Atom = 'X+3*Y+X',
Eqs = ['X'=_A,'Y'=_B],
T = _A+3*_B+_A
```

[`variable_names/1` exists as a write option](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/variable_names) in ISO, Minerva, Jekejeke, GNU, B, SWI, YAP, and SICStus.

In SICStus, the originator of writing terms to lists, one writes:

```
:- use_module(library(codesio)).

term_to_atom(T, Eqs, Atom) :-
   write_term_to_codes(T, Codes, [variable_names(Eqs),quoted(true)]),
   atom_codes(Atom, Codes).
```

The following was an ISO incompatible work around for YAP prior to 6.3.4. It is no longer necessary. As for the differences to a separate write option: `term_to_atom/3` as defined below interferes with constraints and does not correctly render `'$VAR'/1`.

> But for the moment we can only approximate the ideal option
>   `variable_names/1`. To print terms with our own variable names,
>   variables have to be substituted in YAP by `'$VAR'(Codes)` where
>   `Codes` is a list of character codes. This does not do exactly the
>   same, but it is very close. This goes into a file:
>
> ```
> :- use_module(library(apply)).
> :- use_module(library(lambda)).
>
> write_eqs_term(T, Eqs) :-
>    \+ \+ ( 
>            maplist(\Eq^( Eq = (N='$VAR'(Chs)), atom_codes(N,Chs)), Eqs),
>            write_term(T,[numbervars(true),quoted(true)])
>    ).
>
> term_to_atom(T, Eqs, A) :-
>    with_output_to(atom(A), write_eqs_term(T, Eqs) ).
> ```
>
> For SWI, you would have to replace `atom_codes(N,Chs)` by `N = Ch`.
>   and install [`library(lambda)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl) first.  It's pre-installed in YAP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a bit puzzled, could you be so kind of giving me an example ?. I understood from your answer that it is not term_to_atom/2 what I should use, but still I have not gotten how to do it with with_output_to/2 (sorry, I am far from being a Prolog expert :)

Comment: I didn't find '$VAR'(String) in ISO.

Comment: @CookieMonster: Your comment is no longer relevant!

Comment: @CookieMonster: Almost. With [8 systems](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/variable_names) supporting the write-option, $VAR is no longer relevant for this question.