# prolog - print the value of a variable

Tags: variables, prolog, return-value

I just cannot figure out how to print the value of `X`. Here is what I tried in the toplevel:

```
59 ?- read(X).
|: 2.
X = 2.

60 ?- write(X).
_G253
true.
```

What is `_G253`? I dont want the index number, I want the value X is bound to.
What should I do in order to print the value of `X`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable Names in SWI Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358623/variable-names-in-swi-prolog)

Answer (score 23):

When you type `write(X).` at the interactive prompt, and nothing else, X is not bound to anything in particular.  If you want to read X from the user and then write it, try typing `read(X), write(X).` at the prompt.

```
?- read(X), write(X).
|: 28.
28
X = 28.
```

SWI Prolog does keep a history of top-level bindings; type `help.` to go into the manual, then search for `bindings` or just navigate to section 2.8 of the manual, 'Reuse of top-level bindings'.  There, you can learn that the most recent value of any variable bound in a successful top-level goal is retained, and can be referred to using the name of the variable, prefixed with a dollar sign.  So interactions like the following are possible:

```
?- read(X).
|: 42.
X = 42.

?- write($X).
42
true.
```

But a top-level goal that just happens to use the variable name X will be interpreted as using a fresh variable; to do otherwise would violate the normal semantics of Prolog.

Answer (score 2):

prolog - take as input and print the value of a variable.

```
go:- write('Enter a name'),nl,
  read(Name),nl,
  print(Name).
print(Name):- write(Name),write(', Hello !!!').
```