# How can I print unification results when using prolog script?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog, unification

I'm using prolog script to do all queries, the code goes like:

```
:- initialization(run).

writeln(T) :- write(T), nl.

queryAll :-
    forall(query(Q), (Q ->
        writeln('yes':Q) ;
        writeln('no ':Q))).

run :-
    queryAll,
    halt.

query( (1,2,3) = (X,Y,Z) ).
```

the problem is that `queryAll` will only print "yes" or "no" while I want to see the unification results like:

```
X = 1
Y = 2
Z = 3
```

How to do this in prolog?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if I run in gprolog, after adding forall/2, I see `yes:((1,2,3)=(1,2,3))`. You could try `format('yes:~w~n', [Q])` instead of writeln(yes:Q), but seems you have some other problem. Do you need to see the variables names?

Comment: Please note that you can read **and** write out variable names conveniently in GNU-Prolog (recent versions) using the option `variable_names/1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here a sample of gprolog builtins that could be useful to build a better experience for your customers:

```
| ?- read_term_from_atom('X+Y = 1+2.', T, [variable_names(L)]).

L = ['X'=A,'Y'=B]
T = A+B=1+2

yes
| ?- read_term_from_atom('X+Y = 1+2.', T, [variable_names(L)]),call(T).

L = ['X'=1,'Y'=2]
T = 1+2=1+2
```

Note that you should change the query/1 content: instead of

```
query( (1,2,3) = (X,Y,Z) ).
```

should be

```
query( '(1,2,3) = (X,Y,Z).' ). % note the dot terminated atom
```

and then the loop could be, for instance

```
queryAll :-
    forall(query(Q), 
        ( read_term_from_atom(Q, T, [variable_names(L)]),
          ( T -> writeln('yes':L) ; writeln('no ':Q) )
        )).
```

I get the hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948525/874024) answer.

Answer (score 1):

In GNU Prolog you can avoid the final dot when passnig the `end_of_term(eof)` option to `read_term_from_atom`. E.g.,:

```
| ?- read_term_from_atom('X+Y = 1+2', T, [variable_names(L),end_of_term(eof)]).

L = ['X'=A,'Y'=B]
T = (A+B=1+2)``
```

This means that when an EOF (end of file) is encountered it is considered as the end of the term being read. When reading from an atom, EOF corresponds to the then of the string representation of the atom.

This can simplify things in some situations.