# For length/2 how to add human readable variable names

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

How can human readable variable names be displayed for system generated variable names?

As a simple example:

```
?- length(Ls,N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [_5112],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [_5112, _5118],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [_5112, _5118, _5124],
N = 3
```

would be nicer as

```
?- length(Ls,N).
Ls = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [a],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [a, b],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [a, b, c],
N = 3
```

mapping

```
_5112 = a
_5118 = b
_5124 = c
```

---

**Details**

The closest solution I found uses [read_term/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_term/2) as demonstrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21308115/1243762) with the `variable_names(Vars)` option, however my problem does not use `read_term` to get the term from the console.

If this is a duplicate let me know; I could not find one.

---

The real problem is based on generating test case data:

```
?- length(Ls,N),list_partitionedNU(Ls,Ps).
Ls = Ps, Ps = [],
N = 0 ;
Ls = [_5242],
N = 1,
Ps = [[_5242]] ;
Ls = [_5242, _5248],
N = 2,
Ps = [[_5242], [_5248]] ;
Ls = [_5242, _5248],
N = 2,
Ps = [[_5242, _5248]] ;
Ls = [_5242, _5248, _5254],
...
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30148906/1243762) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48255474/1243762) for `list_partitionedNU/2`.

---

Follow up after answers.

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54449640/1243762) by William

```
partitions(Ps) :-
  length(Ls,N),
  assign(Ls),
  list_partitionedNU(Ls,Ps).

?- partitions(Ps).
Ps = [] ;
Ps = [[a]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b]] ;
Ps = [[a, b]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b], [c]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b, c]] ;
Ps = [[a, b], [c]] ;
Ps = [[a, c], [b]] ;
Ps = [[a, b, c]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b], [c], [d]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b], [c, d]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b, c], [d]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b, d], [c]] ;
Ps = [[a], [b, c, d]] ;
Ps = [[a, b], [c], [d]] ;
Ps = [[a, c], [b], [d]] ;
Ps = [[a, d], [b], [c]] ;
Ps = [[a, b], [c, d]] ;
Ps = [[a, c], [b, d]] ;
Ps = [[a, d], [b, c]] ;
Ps = [[a, b, c], [d]] ;
Ps = [[a, b, d], [c]] ;
Ps = [[a, c, d], [b]] ;
Ps = [[a, b, c, d]] ;
...
```

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450139/1243762) by CapelliC

```
partitions(Ps) :-
    length(Ls,N),
    numbervars(Ls,0,N),
    list_partitionedNU(Ls,Ps).

?- partitions(Ps).
Ps = [] ;
Ps = [[A]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B]] ;
Ps = [[A, B]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B], [C]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B, C]] ;
Ps = [[A, B], [C]] ;
Ps = [[A, C], [B]] ;
Ps = [[A, B, C]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B], [C], [D]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B], [C, D]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B, C], [D]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B, D], [C]] ;
Ps = [[A], [B, C, D]] ;
Ps = [[A, B], [C], [D]] ;
Ps = [[A, C], [B], [D]] ;
Ps = [[A, D], [B], [C]] ;
Ps = [[A, B], [C, D]] ;
Ps = [[A, C], [B, D]] ;
Ps = [[A, D], [B, C]] ;
Ps = [[A, B, C], [D]] ;
Ps = [[A, B, D], [C]] ;
Ps = [[A, C, D], [B]] ;
Ps = [[A, B, C, D]] ;
...
```

Comment: You could "walk" through the functor, and each time assign variables you obtain the next "name" you store in an accumulator.

Comment: Beware constraints! You are unifying actual variables that might be connected to constraints. For your example, consider `length(Xs, 5),clpfd:all_different(Xs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can construct a predicate that "assigns" values to the variables in a functor in a recursive fasion, with an accumulator that keeps track of the latest "name" assigned.

For example:

```
assign(Term) :-
    assign(Term, 97, _).

assign(X, N, N1) :-
    var(X),
    !,
    char_code(X, N),
    N1 is N+1.
assign(F, N, N1) :-
    F =.. [_|A],
    assign_list(A, N, N1).

assign_list([], N, N).
assign_list([H|T], N, NT) :-
    assign(H, N, N1),
    assign_list(T, N1, NT).
```

For example:

```
?- length(L, _), assign(L).
L = [] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, b, c] ;
L = [a, b, c, d] ;
L = [a, b, c, d, e] ;
L = [a, b, c, d, e, f] .
?- Q = [L, [_, _]], length(L, _), assign(Q).
Q = [[], [a, b]],
L = [] ;
Q = [[a], [b, c]],
L = [a] ;
Q = [[a, b], [c, d]],
L = [a, b] ;
Q = [[a, b, c], [d, e]],
L = [a, b, c] .
```

We thus "walk" through the tree and assign values to the variables. With the above implementation we do *not* take into account existing constants. So we might assign values that already exist to the variables. Furthermore we just keep incrementing the character code, so eventually we will reach symbols, control characters, and characters.

The above shortcomings can however be "solved" by first inspecting the functor and obtaining a list of constants to skip. Furthermore the generator of terms can of course be improved, for example by yielding `aa` after `z`.

@DanielLyons pointed to the [**`term_variables/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_variables/2) predicate, which can ease the `assign/1` predicate a lot, like:

```
assign(Term) :-
    term_variables(Term, Vars),
    assign_list(Vars, 97).

assign_list([], _).
assign_list([H|T], N) :-
    char_code(H, N),
    N1 is N+1,
    assign_list(T, N1).
```

This of course still does not solves the above stated shortcomings, although, as said, we can solve these by using something else than `char_code` to obtain a constant name, and by first making a wak to look for constants in use.

Answer (score 4):

Let's not forget the obvious option: a different Prolog processor.

Using SICStus Prolog 4.5.0 ([try full-featured SICStus Prolog 30 days for free](https://sicstus.sics.se/eval.html)):

```
| ?- Xs = [_C,f(_E)|_], length(Xs,N).
N = 2, Xs = [_C,f(_E)] ? ;
N = 3, Xs = [_C,f(_E),_A] ? ;
N = 4, Xs = [_C,f(_E),_A,_B] ? ;
N = 5, Xs = [_C,f(_E),_A,_B,_D] ? ;
N = 6, Xs = [_C,f(_E),_A,_B,_D,_F] ? ;
N = 7, Xs = [_C,f(_E),_A,_B,_D,_F,_G] ? ...
```

Comment: Remarkable how SICStus avoids already used variable names `_C` and `_E`

Comment: @false. Smart indeed. Why is there no portable "best" toplevel?

Comment: That needs to be written

Answer (score 2):

The oldie but goldie [numbervars/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numbervars/3) has been revisited:

```
?- length(L,5),numbervars(L,0,N).
L = [A, B, C, D, E],
N = 5.
```

not sure it's really useful, but it is nice to explore...

```
?- length(L,5),numbervars(L,0'a,N).
L = [T3, U3, V3, W3, X3],
N = 102.
```

Comment: We can use that in combination with [`term_variables/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_variables/2) to let it work on arbitrary terms.

Comment: What exactly has been revisited in `numbervars/3`?

Comment: @false: IRC was once more a pattern like '$VAR'(N). But I'm not so sure, let me know... anyway, I left implicit that even if we get such pattern, a maplist could be applied to make sense of the data.

Comment: (What do you mean by IRC ...??) `numbervars/3` is defined as ever with `'$VAR'/1` terms

Comment: @false: sorry, was IIRC ... a mistake in mistake :)

Comment: @CapelliC in SWI, try `length(L,5),numbervars(L,0,N) ; true.`. when presented with `;`, press "w". :) (to undo, repeat, and press "p".)

Comment: (of course `write_canonical` does the same, but "w" is less keys to type :) ).