# Limiting variable scope in prolog

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

I want to declare a list of lists, like so:

```
%% example 1
Xs = [
  [[A],[[A]]], 
  [[A],[[A],[A]]], 
  [[A],[[A],[A],[A]]]
].
```

Here, the symbol `A` refers to the same variable in each list. Executing maplist(writeln,xs) results in the following output:

```
[[_G1],[[_G1]]]
[[_G1],[[_G1],[_G1]]]
[[_G1],[[_G1],[_G1],[_G1]]]
```

I want to use the same symbol `A` in each list, but for the variable to be distinct for each list, to give the following output:

```
[[_G1],[[_G1]]]
[[_G2],[[_G2],[_G2]]]
[[_G3],[[_G3],[_G3],[_G3]]]
```

The only way I make this work is give each list its own unique variable, like so:

```
%% example 2
Xs = [
  [[A1],[[A1]]], 
  [[A2],[[A2],[A2]]], 
  [[A3],[[A3],[A3],[A3]]]
].
```

Is there any Prolog syntax, so that there is no need to number each variable, as per example 2? I tried adding brackets around the lists like so:

```
Xs = [
  ([[A],[[A]]]), 
  ([[A],[[A],[A]]]), 
  ([[A],[[A],[A],[A]]])
].
```

But this gives me the same output as example 1.

Comment: I think that the same name meaning the same is nice. But you can try copy_term to copy one list and create new variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

First, create the desired list structure, with *different* variables:

```
?- maplist(length, Lists, [2,3,4]).
Lists = [[X1, X2], [X3, X4, X5], [X6, X7, X8, X9]].
```

Then, using the following additional definition:

```
same_element(Ls) :- maplist(=([_]), Ls).
```

you can *unify* variables that are in the same sublist to the same term:

```
?- maplist(same_element, [[X1, X2], [X3, X4, X5], [X6, X7, X8, X9]]).
X1 = X2, X2 = [_G1141],
X3 = X4, X4 = X5, X5 = [_G1149],
X6 = X7, X7 = X8, X8 = X9, X9 = [_G1157].
```

In combination:

```
?- maplist(length, Lists, [2,3,4]),
   maplist(same_element, Lists),
   maplist(writeln, Lists).
```

yielding:

```
[[_G1079],[_G1079]]
[[_G1087],[_G1087],[_G1087]]
[[_G1095],[_G1095],[_G1095],[_G1095]]
```

Now, with the following Emacs definitions:

```
(defun nice-variables (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (goto-char start)
  (let ((n 1)
        (variables nil)
        (m (make-marker)))
    (set-marker m end)
    (while (and (<= (point) (marker-position m))
                (re-search-forward "_G" (marker-position m) t))
      (let* ((from (point))
             (len (skip-chars-forward "0-9"))
             (str (buffer-substring-no-properties from (+ from len)))
             (num (assoc str variables)))
        (delete-backward-char (+ len 2))
        (if num
            (insert (format "X%d" (cdr num)))
          (setq variables (cons (cons str n) variables))
          (insert (format "X%d" n))
          (setq n (1+ n)))))))
```

and `M-x nice-variables RET` on the region, you get:

```
[[X1],[X1]]
[[X2],[X2],[X2]]
[[X3],[X3],[X3],[X3]]
```

This is also what I used on the output of the first query above, to make it more readable.

Thus, you can either generate the structure you want dynamically, by unifying variables you want to be the same, or copy & paste the output above and use it with slight modifications in your program directly.

Comment: It seems, your Elisp program assumes that the newly introduced variables do not occur in the initial text.

Comment: The main assumptions are (1) that, as is the case in the question, the system-introduced variables are of the form `_G<digits>`, and (2) that these variables either do not appear at all in the query, or, in case they do appear, that their corresponding replacement (`X<other_digits>`) does not appear in the query. It would be interesting to make these definitions more general, using Prolog to detect suitable variable names that do not conflict with variables that already occur in the query. Currently, the definitions are only correct in the cases above, which cover many typical situations.

Comment: They do not cover the quite typical situation of pasting answers back.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names in Prolog have a scope that spans a single clause in a predicate definition, or a query at the top-level. So, this:

```
?- List = [A, A, A].
```

means a list with three times the same variable, `A`. If you put it into a predicate, it would be, say in a file `my_lists.pl` (I have not nested the lists like you, just to keep it simple):

```
my_list([A, A]).
my_list([A, A, A]).
my_list([A, A, A, A]).
```

The `A`s in the three clauses are now not in the same lexical scope, so if you consult this predicate and then collect all possible instantiations of `my_list(L)` using for example `findall/3`, you get what you are after:

```
?- [my_lists].
true.

?- findall(L, my_list(L), Ls).
Ls = [[_G1945, _G1945],
      [_G1933, _G1933, _G1933],
      [_G1918, _G1918, _G1918, _G1918]].
```

Is this close to what you are looking for? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write out variables and specify a precise name for them, you need the write-option `variable_names/1`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948525/772868) explains how. Alternatively, you might use the legacy predicate `numbervars/3` which unifies distinct variables with a term `'$VAR'(N)`, and then use either `writeq/1` or the write-option `numbervars(true)`.

But both methods will not work in the case you indicate.  In fact, it was sheer luck that your query

```
 ?- Xs = [[[A],[A]],[[A],[A],[A]],[[A],[A],[A],[A]]], maplist(writeln,Xs).
```

produced the same variables for the different lists. It's even worse, the very same goal writing the very same list, may produce different variable names for different invocations:

```
p(N) :-
   length(_,N),
   length(K,1),
   writeq(K),
   garbage_collect,
   writeq(K).
```

For `p(100)`, SICStus writes `[_776][_46]`, SWI writes `[_G517][_G3]`. Brief, you caught Prolog on a good day. This is not surprising, for the standard only requires an "implementation dependent" value for a name with a few restrictions: It starts with underscore, and the remaining characters are different for different variables, and the same for the same variable **within the same write goal**. Here is ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 on this:

> #### 7.10.5 Writing a term
>
> When a term `Term` is output using `write_term/3` (8.14.2)
> the action which is taken is defined by the rules below:
>
> > a) If `Term` is a variable, a character sequence repre-
> > senting that variable is output. The sequence begins
> > with _ (underscore) and the remaining characters are
> > implementation dependent. The same character sequence
> > is used for each occurrence of a particular variable in
> > `Term`. A different character sequence is used for each
> > distinct variable in `Term`.

The reason for this is that a globally consistent naming of variables would produce a lot of overhead in implementations.

To summarize: If you want to use different variable names for the same variable, then use `variable_names/1` with different arguments. If you want the variable to be actually different, then name them differently, or use `copy_term/2` accordingly.