# How to preserve a variable name in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a program which evaluates a function and does some operations on it.

```
dynamic evaluate/2.
begin :- writeln("Write your function"), read(Line),  
              assert((evaluate(X, Y) :- Y is Line)).
```

Since in SWI-prolog variable names are changed to _«number», when I try to call evaluate(), it doesn't work.

Any solutions to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you want.  For variable names [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948525/772868).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `read_term/2` (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read_term/2) with the `variable_names` option instead of `read(Line)`:

```
read_term(Line, [variable_names(['X'=X])])
```