# How to print on the screen unbound variables? Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to print the list of unbound variables to the screen.

```
12 ?- write([X, Y]).

[_G1696,_G1699]
```

But I want to see in fact [X, Y] on the screen instead of `[_G1696,_G1699]`. Is it possible? How?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7948525/772868) how to write and read variable names in a general manner.

Comment: `write_term([X,Y],[variable_names(['X'=X,'Y'=Y])]).`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to *pretty print* terms with unbound variables? You can use the de facto standard `numbervars/3` predicates to accomplish it. For example:

```
pretty_print_term(Stream, Term) :-
    \+ \+ (
        numbervars(Term, 0, _),
        write_term(Stream, Term, [numbervars(true)])).

pretty_print_term_quoted(Stream, Term) :-
    \+ \+ (
        numbervars(Term, 0, _),
        write_term(Stream, Term, [numbervars(true), quoted(true)])).
```

In these snippets, double negation is used to pretty print a term while discarding the instantiation of the variables by the `numbervars/3` predicate.

An usage example:

```
?- current_output(Stream), pretty_print_term_quoted(Stream, [X, Y]).
[A,B]
Stream = <stream>(0x10bebcf18).
```

Comment: Thank you! But can't I force numbervars/3 to select same variables name? (exactly X, Y instead of A, B )

Comment: @Svetlana You cannot do that with `numbervars/3`.