# print list of variable names in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm using the swi-prolog build in predicate to get a list of variables from a term.
I am then trying to print them out with their sequence number.
Unfortunately I'm only able to print their internal _2902 names instead of X,Y, etc.
Is there a way to preserve the names? preferably not implementation dependant.
Here is what I have:

```
assign_numbers(Term) :-
    term_variables(Term, L),
    print_values(L,0).



% take a list of variables and print them out with their index according to their appearance order.

print_values([],_). 
print_values([X|Xs],C) :-
    C1 is C + 1,
    write(X),tab(1),write(=),tab(1),write(C1),nl,
    print_values(Xs,C1).
```

As a side question I would also like to see the implementation of the build in predicate term_variables from swi-prolog but I cant find it.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948525/772868).